# Probability of getting two subsets with the same sum

Tags: pr.probability, sumsets

Let $A=\{1,...,n\}$. Two subsets of $A$, not necessarily distinct, chosen uniformly at random. What is the probability that both subsets have the same sum? Alternatively, is there a known upper bound?

Comment: Just to be sure, "subsets … chosen uniformly at random" means that each subset has probability $2^{-n}$ of being chosen (so that the question is really how many pairs of subsets have the same sum), right?

Answer (score 6):

Assuming the two subsets are selected independently, the probability in question is
$$p_n=a_n/2^{2n},$$
where $a_n$ the sum of the squares of the coefficients in the polynomial
$$\prod_{k=1}^n (1+x^k).$$
The sequence $(a_n)$ is the sequence [A047653](https://oeis.org/A047653), and its asymptotics, given on that page, is
$$a_n\sim\frac{\sqrt{3/\pi}\,4^n}{n^{3/2}} \tag{1}$$
(as $n\to\infty$). So,
$$p_n\sim\frac{\sqrt{3/\pi}}{n^{3/2}}.\tag{2}$$

---

For (1), [A047653](https://oeis.org/A047653) refers to [Vaclav Kotesovec](https://oeis.org/wiki/User:Vaclav_Kotesovec), where I have been unable to find a link/reference to (1). However, the equivalent relation (2) was actually proved by [van Lint](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1967-018-01/S0002-9939-1967-0205964-8/S0002-9939-1967-0205964-8.pdf). (I found a link to van Lint on the related OEIS page [A000980](https://oeis.org/A000980).)

Comment: $a_n = s_n$, right?

Comment: @LSpice : Thank you for your comment. I am sorry for the confusion. I was hesitating between $s_n$ (for the sum of the squares) and $a_n$ (the notation used on the linked page). Now this typo  is fixed.

Comment: The asymptotic comes from the integral $$4^n\int_{0}^{1} \left(\prod_{k=1}^{n} \cos^2(\pi kt) \right)dt$$. But how to calculate the integral?

Comment: @AlapanDas : I have added a response to your comment.